# Game Program is skipping

Tags: c#, .net

Am trying to run a game I've made of 5 classes, but the most important part isn't running. keep in mind that am still a beginner in c#. All the 5 classes are separate but I only typed the namespaces in the first class here as to avoid confusion, they are there in each class. The program runs but when it reaches the Battle class it skips the BattleLoop completely and asks if i want to play again...Please help me.

First class (my entry point):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainGame maingame = new MainGame();
    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
class MainGame
{
    Hero myhero;
    Battle battle;
    string answer; 

    public MainGame()
    {
        myhero = new Hero();
        Hero.Initialize(myhero);
        BasicGameLoop();

    }

    void BasicGameLoop()
    {
        do 
        {
            Monster monster = new Monster();
            battle = new Battle(myhero, monster);
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Play again??");
            answer= Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while(answer == "Y" || answer == "y");
    }
}
```

Third class:

```
class Battle
{
    string choice;
    Random rand;
    int healing, fleechance, hitchance;

    public Battle(Hero hero, Monster monster)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is facing a {1}.", hero.Identifier, monster.Identifier);
    }

    public void BattleLoop(Hero hero, Monster monster)
    {                                                                     
        do
        {
            rand = new Random();
            DisplayChoices();
            choice = Console.ReadLine();
            hitchance = rand.Next(0, 100);
            switch (choice)
            {
                case "a":
                case "A"://this way a or A work
                    hitchance = rand.Next(0, 100);
                    if (hitchance > 30)
                    {
                        hero.AttackDamage = GetHeroDamage(hero);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} Attacks!", hero.Identifier);
                        hero.AttackDamage -= monster.Defense;
                        Console.WriteLine("The Monster Loses {0}hp", hero.AttackDamage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} Missed!", hero.Identifier);
                    }
                    break;
                case "d":
                case "D":
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Defends", hero.Identifier);
                    break;
                case "h":
                case "H":
                    healing = 400;
                    hero.CurrentHealth += healing;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} uses a Potion!", hero.Identifier);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} heals himself for {1} Points",hero.Identifier,healing);
                    break;
                case "f":
                case "F":
                    fleechance = rand.Next(0, 100);
                    if (fleechance > 40)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} fled!",hero.Identifier);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Fleeing Failed");
                        Console.ReadLine();

                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry that choice was invalid and the monster took a cheap shot!");
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            if (monster.isAlive == true)
            {
                hitchance = rand.Next(0, 100);
                if (hitchance > 30)
                {
                    monster.Strength = GetMonsterDamage(monster);
                    Console.WriteLine("The Monster Attacks!");
                    if (choice == "d" || choice == "D")
                    {
                        monster.Strength /= 2;
                    }
                    monster.Strength -= hero.Defense;
                    Console.WriteLine("The Hero loses {0}hp", monster.Strength);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The Monster Missed!");

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
        while (hero.isAlive == true && monster.isAlive == true);

        if (hero.CurrentHealth > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} emerged Victorious!", hero.Identifier);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has been defeated :(", hero.Identifier);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void PrintStatus(Hero hero, Monster monster)
    {
        Console.Write(@"
   ********************************
             HP/MaxHP     MP/MaxMP
     {0}:   {1}/{2}hp    {3}/{4}mp
     {5}:   {6}/{7}hp    {8}/{9}mp
   ********************************
    ", hero.Identifier, hero.CurrentHealth, hero.MaxHealth, hero.CurrentMagic,       hero.MaxMagic,
    monster.Identifier, monster.CurrentHealth, monster.MaxHealth, monster.CurrentMagic,
    monster.MaxMagic);

    }
    string DisplayChoices()
    {
        string choice;
        Console.Write(@"
  __________________________
   Please Choose an action:
   (A)ttack
   (D)efend
   (H)eal
   (F)lee
   __________________________");
        Console.WriteLine();
        choice = Console.ReadLine();
        return choice;
    }

    public int GetHeroDamage(Hero hero)// 2nd Method to calculate the hero's Damage during battle.
    {
        int attackdamage;
        attackdamage = hero.AttackDamage;
        return attackdamage;
    }
    int GetMonsterDamage(Monster monster) // 3rd Method to calculate the monster's damage during the battle.
    {
        int attackdamage;
        attackdamage = monster.Strength;
        return attackdamage;
    }

}
```

Fourth class"

```
class Hero
{
    public int CurrentHealth, MaxHealth, CurrentMagic;
    public int MaxMagic, Strength, Defense, Agility;
    public int Experience, Gold, AttackDamage;
    public string Identifier;
    public bool isAlive;

    public Hero()
    {
    }
    public static void Initialize(Hero hero)
    {
        hero.CurrentHealth = 18;
        hero.MaxHealth = 18;
        hero.CurrentMagic = 8;
        hero.MaxMagic = 8;
        hero.Strength = 10;
        hero.Defense = 3;
        hero.Agility = 6;
        hero.Experience = 0;
        hero.Gold = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("What is your Hero's name?");
        hero.Identifier = Console.ReadLine();
        hero.isAlive = true;
        hero.AttackDamage = hero.Strength;
    }
  }
```

Fifth class:

```
class Monster
{
    public int CurrentHealth, MaxHealth, CurrentMagic;
    public int MaxMagic, Strength, Defense, Agility;
    public int Experience, Gold, AttackDamage;
    public string Identifier;
    public bool isAlive;

    public Monster()
    {
        CurrentHealth = 8;
        MaxHealth = 8;
        CurrentMagic = 0;
        MaxMagic = 0;
        Strength = 5;
        Defense = 3;
        Agility = 4;
        Experience = 5;
        Gold = 2;
        Identifier = "Monster";
        isAlive = true;
        AttackDamage = Strength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Being a beginner is no excuse for a _"here is all my code, please debug it"_ post.

Comment: Also, if you want to post a huge code listing, please use pastebin.com or whatever similar, not just throw it in the quesiton.

Comment: Try using ToUpper() to work out upper and lower case possibilities.  
{while (answer.ToUpper() == "Y")}
{switch(choice.ToUpper())}

I know it's not what you asked, but thought it might help

Comment: sorry bout that fellas, but i have been struggling with the code for at least two hours. thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the call to BattleLoop. Try adding `battle.BattleLoop()` after the line `battle = new Battle(myhero, monster);` in MainGame.BasicGameLoop.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Monster monster = new Monster();
 battle = new Battle(myhero, monster);
 battle.BattleLoop(myhero, monster);
 Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Play again??");
 answer= Console.ReadLine();
```